# How to convert rows into columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named Shift and I am defining OffDays in this table using below mentioned columns.

```
   CREATE TABLE [tbl_Shift](

    [OffDay1] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_Shift_OffDay1]  DEFAULT (N'Sunday'),
    [IsAlternateOffDay2] [bit] NULL,
    [OffDay2] [nvarchar](25) NULL
    )

INSERT INTO [tbl_Shift] VALUES ('Sunday', 'True', 'Saturday')
```

AlternateOffDay is bit so if it is True than OffDay2 can be defined. 
I want the result to be shown like below in case I have OffDay2 as Saturday.

```
Holidays 
----------
Sunday 
Saturday
```

I have tried this but the result comes up in 2 columns and 1 row and also it skips 2nd if first is not null but that's not the problem. I just want them to be in 2 rows.

```
Select DISTINCT ISNULL(OffDay1,OffDay2) from [HRM].[tbl_Shift]
```

Comment: Please add sample structure. it is not clear currently.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal Please check now

Comment: Although still not clear but with assumption SELECT CASE WHEN IsAlternateOffDay2 =0 THEN OffDay1 END) AS Holiday FROM tbl_Shift UNION SELECT CASE WHEN IsAlternateOffDay2 = 1 THEN offDay2 END) As Holiday 
FROM tbl_Shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the simplest solution is to use a `UNION` (which implicitly does a DISTINCT):

(simplified, just add any WHERE clause as necessary to e.g. ignore OffDay2 where the flag is not set)

```
SELECT OffDay1 FROM [HRM].[tbl_Shift]
UNION
SELECT OffDay2 FROM [HRM].[tbl_Shift]
```

Alternatively, you could look into [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) which is used for switching column values to multiple rows. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TheDay
FROM   
   (SELECT OffDay1, OffDay2  
   FROM tbl_Shift) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (TheDay FOR EachDay IN   
      (OffDay1, OffDay2)  
)AS unpvt;
```